# how do I float a div over a background image in a different div

Tags: css, html, nested

In my CSS, I've created a menubar `<div>` and a header `<div>`. My intention is to have the menu line flush with the BOTTOM of the header's background image, so I've nested the menu inside the header. Alas, it's not working, and I can't figure out why.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwwilson66/CJ3Gh/), but I can't figure out how to upload the associated image file, so I've attached the header placeholder image[image: header background placeholder]. I've also uploaded a Wireframe [image: Wireframe] demonstrating what I'm trying to make happen.

If you're not able to view the fiddle, here's my HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3c/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="t2.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------>

<body>
    <div id="header" >
        <div id="menubar">
            <a href="#">home</a>  |  <a href="#">about</a>  |  <a href="#">contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body     {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000064;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

h1    {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    
    color: #000064;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    }

h2    {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    
    color: #000064;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 5%;
    }

h3    {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    
    color: #000064;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 20%;
    }

p    {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000064;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 600px;
    margin: 0px:
    float: bottom;
    }

a    {
    color: #000064;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }

a.visited {
    color: #640064;
    weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

#header {
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(headerblock.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    float: bottom;
    }

#menubar {
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #000064;
    border-style: solid;
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    float: bottom;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 600px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

#menubar a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000064;
        float: bottom;
        }

#menubar a.visited {
    text-decoration: bold;
    color: #000000;
    float: bottom;
        }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the image in a separate div, all inside the header, like so:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="banner"></div><!--
 --><div id="menubar"></div>
</div>
```

Then use `display: inline-block;` on `#banner` and `#menubar`.
Note the HTML comment after `#banner` and before `#menubar`. It's to remove the white space between those elements, you can remove it if you don't care about the blank space. Look at this for more info: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJ3Gh/11/).
By the way, you should use `<ul>` and `<li>` for your navigation.
And use borders on your separators, instead of `|`. That's for presentation, and presentation should be handled with css, not html.

Comment: Thanks for a better idea of nested divs! One thing I don't understand: My banner image is 984px, but your css seems to be forcing it to 600px. Makes sense; banner & menubar block and inline would align next to each other on the bottom edge. However, my plan is to use the full 984px width with the menubar forced to a specific position (600px padding) OVER the banner image. I've been modifying your CSS all morning to try to make that work...but I can't. I've added another image to my question that's a more realistic picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Then there's no need to put the `#banner` div. Just apply the background to the `#header` and set some margin on `#menubar`. Then use some positioning to get it to the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/CJ3Gh/13/

Comment: I am thinking about this way to much. My attempts have been nowhere near as simple. :)  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#menubar` has a padding 600px left that pushes the div out. Also `Float` can not be `Bottom`, It is either `Left` or `Right`.

To make it perfect place a `position:relative` to the header div and `position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px;` to the child div place it exactly

Answer (score 0):

The `float` parameter accepts `left` or `right`. There is no such thing as `float: bottom`.

But if you add `position: relative` to the header div. You can position the menu with `position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;`

**Update**

You might have to specify a width for the menu bar, te prevent the text from wrapping downwards.